# Parse json in jquery and java

Tags: java, jquery, json

Hi i am trying to make code for parse json in jquery and command comes from java controller and i didn't get solution

```
urlAddCountry="countries/countrylist";
getAjaxCountry(urlAddCountry, CountryDetails, true,true);


function CountryDetails(res)
{
    alert(res);
}

function getAjaxCountry(urlAddCountry, func, isToken,isContentHeader)
{

    var url=serviceURL + urlAdd;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        //isasync: isAsync,
        contentType : "application/json",
        beforeSend:function(xhr){
            if(isContentHeader){
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            } 
            if(isToken){
                xhr.setRequestHeader("tokenId",sessionStorage.tokenID);
            }
        },
        success: function(res) {
            alert(res);
            func(res);
        },
        error : function(err) {
            func(err);
            alert("ERROR:STATUS- " + err.status + "; RESPONSETEXT- " + err.responseText + "; STATUSTEXT- " + err.statusText);
            //return null;
        }
    });

}

[{"entry_id":1,"countryName":"India","phoneCode":"91","countryCode":"IN","isBlackListedForPGTran":"0"},{"entry_id":2,"countryName":"Timor-Leste","phoneCode":"NULL","countryCode":"TL","isBlackListedForPGTran":"0"}]
```

Comment: Does the console log any errors? Please specify the problem.

Comment: for single rows it works but for multiple rows it gives following alert [object object]

Comment: The answer of sakir should fix this.

Comment: Getting [object object] doesn't have to mean something bad. Try `console.log(x)` instead of `alert(x)`.

Comment: not working console.log(x)

Comment: are you sure about this: `var url=serviceURL + urlAdd` ? You're using 2 undefined variables, and your variable `urlAddCountry` is unused in `getAjaxCountry`. Then, be sure that your server returns a JSON **string**. Finally, don't use `alert(res)` but prefer `console.log(res)`. If you don't know what the console is, use Google Chrome (then see this https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/console#using-the-console-api) or Firefox with [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/firebug/). If you can't use them, have a look to Firebug Lite (https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite).

Answer (score 1):

According to what i understood from comments, you can use [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to stringify your json so that you can see it.

```js
var jsonArray = [{"entry_id":1,"countryName":"India","phoneCode":"91","countryCode":"IN","isBlackListedForPGTran":"0"},{"entry_id":2,"countryName":"Timor-Leste","phoneCode":"NULL","countryCode":"TL","isBlackListedForPGTran":"0"}]

alert(JSON.stringify(jsonArray));
```

Parsing means, to convert a json string into an object. If you alert an object, you'll see corresponding structure like `[object object]` as you mentioned in comments.

Comment: Since when can you execute code snippets on stackoverflow? That's a nice feature. Thank you for that. +1 therefore

Comment: @Loki see [introduction](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers)  and [Stack snippets 2.0](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270944/feedback-requested-stack-snippets-2-0)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code in your success callback:

```
var json = $.parseJSON(yourjsondatahere);
$(json).each(function(i,val){
    $.each(val,function(k,v){
        console.log(k+" : "+ v);     
    });
});
```

Comment: in your case yourjsondatahere =res

Comment: not working   success: function(res) {
     
   var json = $.parseJSON(res);
   $(json).each(function(i,val){
   
   $.each(val,function(k,v){
   console.log(k+" : "+ v);     
   });
   });
      

            func(res);
     },

Comment: SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 2 of the JSON data

Answer (score 0):

Try following using `jquery`

```
var json = jQuery.parseJSON(res);
    $.each(json, function(k, v) {
        console.log(k+' :: '+v);
    });
```

While in `Java` you need to use `Json Librabry`.

For download visit [this](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/downloads/list) link and for tutorial visit [this](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/json/java-json-parser-example/) link.